# Csh getting variables as a list

Tags: awk, foreach, csh

Hi I'm studying Csh programming these days. And I'm having a problem with dealing with the variables.

The input file(TEST) is followed by.

```
cat TEST
Tom   sony78   man   E5
Jam    jimmy65 man   E5
```

I want an OUTPUT file which has a format like this.

```
**Tom** is **man**, He(SHE) is **E5**
**Jam** is **man**, He(SHE) is **E5**
```

For trying to get this Variable.

Here is my code and it can't store the column of TOM and JAM in {print $1}. I'm confused

```
set path1 = `TEST`
set Name = `echo $path1 | awk -F " " '{print $1}'`
set ID = `echo $path1 | awk -F " " '{print $2}'` 
set sex = `echo $path1 | awk -F " " '{print $3}'` 
set Rank = `echo $path1 | awk -F " " '{print $4}'`
```

Comment: hi, it would be simpler in bash or another shell. but in `csh` you can read a file with `foreach x (\`cat file\`) echo $x`

Comment: Yes I've tried the way but it isn't working to get the output I want.

Comment: The most important thing to learn about csh programming is - don't do it. [Google csh why not.](https://www.google.com/search?q=csh+why+not).

Comment: Since you're already using `awk`, why not let it do the work?  Perhaps `awk '{ printf "**%s** is **%s**, He(SHE) is **%s**\n", $1, $3, $4 }' < TEST`